# Can I use Spring framework for android development?

Tags: java, android, spring, frameworks

I'm building my android app and wanted to know if spring framework is fine for android development?  I heard there is spring-android and others but still not sure as why they're better for android development vs spring framework.

So as far as the server side code goes is spring ok to use for android development?

Comment: I disagree with closing as OT here, because the question (while a little ambiguous) is asking about the relationship between backends and mobile clients. It is probably a candidate for closing as a duplicate if there's a suitable match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your backend language is almost entirely irrelevant to a mobile application. You will probably be using a network-based API to communicate between the two, and any backend that can speak your preferred protocol will suffice. These days, JSON over HTTP is a common default choice, and Spring supports it out of the box with literally no configuration required (and makes using OAuth very easy, which is nice for mobile applications), but you could choose any backend you like.

Spring Android is an Android-friendly implementation of a few Spring client features, notably `RestTemplate`, and entirely agnostic of the backend it's talking to. These days, Retrofit and Volley seem to be more popular choices for Android, and both will work just fine with a Spring backend.

Comment: thanks this cleared it up.